# Why I get:97: binary operator expected

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Disk Space Monitoring for more than 96%
# Aand shuting down servers

# Declare Variebles
used_space=0
mount_point="/apps/"
threshold=$96%
DOMAIN_HOME=/apps/oracle/product/Middleware/user_projects/domains/cbs_idm_dom
EMAIL_ADDR=user@host
MW_BASE=/apps/oracle/product/Middleware
used_space=`df -k $mount_point | grep % | awk {'print $4'} | sed 's/%//g'`
#print "Free space available under \"$mount_point\" is `expr 100 - $used_space`%.\n"

if [ $used_space >= $threshold ]
echo $MESSAGE | mailx -s "Alert:Server disk is full - shutting down server." $EMAIL_ADDR
#sleep 60
then
#Shutdown OID in this host

# STOP

source $MW_BASE/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh

#STOP OPMN

#$MW_BASE/idm_inst/bin/opmnctl stopall > /apps/oracle/product/Middleware/scripts/logs/stop_idm_inst.log &

#$MW_BASE/idm_sync/bin/opmnctl stopall > /apps/oracle/product/Middleware/scripts/logs/stop_idm_sync.log &

#Stop Weblogic

$DOMAIN_HOME/bin/stopManagedWebLogic.sh wls_ods1 > /apps/oracle/product/Middleware/scripts/logs/stop_wls_ods2.log &

else
echo "INVALID OPTION"
fi;
```

Comment: There's a bunch of syntax errors in this script. It would be best if you could reduce it to a snippet that exhibits the single issue that you want help with. Or, at least, [edit] your question to paste the exact error message that you get.

Comment: @dhag fwiw the exact error message was in the title

Answer (score 4):

The cause of the error is this pair of lines

```
threshold=$96%
...
if [ $used_space >= $threshold ]
```

The first one sets threshold to something entirely unlike what I suspect you thing it's doing. Mainly because you haven't quoted the string, but partly because there's a `$` in here that doesn't even make semantic sense:

```
threshold=$96%
echo ">$threshold<"    # >6%<
```

The `...` code I've omitted manages to set `used_space=97`, so you then come to the comparison, which isn't really a comparison at all. The `>` redirects output from the test into the file `=` and then leaves the following to be evaluated as part of the test:

```
[ 97 6% ]
```

which spits out `-bash: [: 97: unary operator expected`. You were probably looking for the `-ge` operator (see `man bash` or even `man test` for details of the operators available to you).

Comment: @drewbenn any of these will provide information about the more standard operators such as `-ge`.